# dialogflow large number of potential parameter values

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

My Google Action delivers information to college students. For example: Who is the Title IX Coordinator?

To answer this question, we need to know the college the student attends. There are 2700+ colleges in the U.S. Many have the same name or similar sounding names.

So, @college-name is an entity in DialogFlow. Is there a way to import all 2700+ college names into DialogFlow as potential values for @college-name?

Also, is there a way to use a listbox with DialogFlow / Actions on Google with Google Assistant to ensure the correct college is identified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dialogflow has the ability to [import entities from a file](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities#upload) either in a CSV or JSON format.

There isn't a listbox visual widget, although you can use a [List](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#list) with similar names or [Suggestion Chips](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#suggestion_chip) to narrow down their search.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to importing entity values from a file you can also push them to Dialogflow programmatically via the [Dialogflow REST API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest). This API manages the agent itself and is thus different from the Dialogflow Webhook, which calls your fulfillment service.

The specific endpoint you would use to update entity values is [projects.agent.entityTypes.entities](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.entityTypes.entities). Dialogflow also offers [SDKs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#v2beta1_client_libraries) for Python, Node.js and other languages. This is probably the best option if you have a large number of values, as it allows you to setup some kind of pipeline from your data source to Dialogflow and schedule it to update the entity on a regular basis (i.e. with an AWS Lambda function or a cron job that runs once a day).